# Enable HTML5 tags on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, html5, css

I really love Eclipse (PDT)... But i'm developing sites using HTML5 and CSS3 and it mark the HTML5 tags like `<nav>`, `<section>` and `<article>`  as invalid tags (inexistent).

How can I add those new tags to it?

And what about CSS3 rules?

I read something about remove the "invalid tag" check... and that's not what I want. :(

Comment: What version of Eclipse you are using ?

Comment: Eclipse Galileo build 20100218-0602 for Windows and Eclipse Galileo build 20100218-1602 (v1.2.2.20100216-1730) for Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not much info is available in the Zend site as regarding HTML5, so it's unclear whether they truly support it.

From examining the Zend Framework source file [Doctype.php](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/View/Helper/Doctype.php), it seems that the DOCTYPE should be declared as simply `<!DOCTYPE html>` in order to support HTML5, which is the correct format according to the [HTML5 specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/#the-doctype).

The error might also come from an HTML validator that you have installed.
In this case, you might be able to adjust its preferences.

I also hope that you have installed the latest [Eclipse PHP Development Tools](http://www.zend.com/en/community/pdt).

Comment: @harrymc - I'm using the PDT... As I said in the question.. The only thing I can do about it is disable the "invalid tag" error.. And that's not correct.

Comment: @TiuTalk: What about my other points - doctype and html validator?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Using a fresh eclipse PTD I just downloaded then -- up to date and no custom validators or anything installed. In my index file I've got <!DOCTYPE html> but the 'view' file with the html5 tags still throw warnings.

Comment: I'm having the same issue as @DeanRather.

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>` did it for me! Thanks.